# document.title problems ie8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, title

Why does IE8 fail to change the documents title with document.title="test title";

Comment: facebook can do it, so there has to be a way. I need to make my site work on IE so :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works on IE8 for me. But I did get the ActiveX security popup, so perhaps your IE8 is not set to prompt for these issues and just deny scripting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeTitle() {
        document.title = 'Foobar';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="changeTitle()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.title does work, the function was not firing thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Really? Using `document.title = 'Foo Bar';` has always worked for me. Is your script even executing?

Try shoving this right before the `document.title = ...`:

```
alert('I work.');
```

If you don't get an alert box, your script isn't even running.

Answer (score 0):

found this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296113

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">

function runTest()
{
    var s ="We should set this as the new title" 
    var mytitle = document.createElement("TITLE");
    mytitle.innerHTML = s;
    alert(s);       
    document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(mytitle);

}
function fix()
{
    var s = "Now we change the title";
    alert(s);
    document.title = s; 
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<input type="button" value="Problem" onclick="runTest()"/>
<input type="button" value="Workaround" onclick="fix()"/>
</BODY>
```

for me this is works in IE 9,8,7

maybe you dont call your function, or there is something which not works.

the document.title must work!

Comment: The `fix()` is the thing that's broken. And how is this an answer?

Comment: what is your problem with my asnwer?

Comment: You posted the contents of an article and then edited your answer 5 minutes later, but I commented on the original post. When you just post code, it's doing the work *for* the OP and not helping them.